# URL ID removed after submit? (ASP.NET / Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a program that allows the user to add and confirm orders. On one page is the table with all orders (confirmed and unconfirmed). Each order is situated on each row of the table, and each order row has a "Confirm Order" button, that once clicked, redirects the user to a new view, where the user is then able to add this specific orders details - a single order can consist of multiple rows, all rows eventually constituting as a single order. Each row within the order has a Product Name, Quantity, Price and Supplier - Three of these attributes (Product Name, Quantity and Supplier) are selected by the user using inputs situated within a begin form.

What i have done:

I am using an onclick location.href event to pass the clicked buttons ID to the relevant action result:

```
onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("ConfirmOrderPage","Home", new { id = order.OrderID })'"
```

order.OrderID is created using a foreach loop, which dynamically assigns an ID to each "Confirm Order" button - so the ID of the button clicked, will be the ID of the order the user wishes to confirm.

The following action result is where the id is being sent to:

```
public ActionResult ConfirmOrderPage(int id)
        {
            //Disable Lazy Loading
            DBAccessor.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            //Clear list
            confirmedOrder.Clear();

            //Create dyanmic object reader that includes all related attributes
            var confirmedDynamicReader = DBAccessor.OrderLine.Where(bb => bb.OrderID == id).Include(zz => zz.Product).Include(aa => aa.Supplier);

            foreach (var confirmedOrderItem in confirmedDynamicReader)
            {
                //Load relevant attributes into view order table
                ConfirmOrderLineViewModel DisplayConfirmedOrders = new ConfirmOrderLineViewModel();
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.OrderID = confirmedOrderItem.OrderID;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.ProductID = confirmedOrderItem.Product.ProductID;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.ProductName = confirmedOrderItem.Product.Name;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.Quantity = confirmedOrderItem.Quantity;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.Price = confirmedOrderItem.Product.Price;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.SupplierID = confirmedOrderItem.Supplier.SupplierID;
                DisplayConfirmedOrders.SupplierName = confirmedOrderItem.Supplier.Name;
                confirmedOrder.Add(DisplayConfirmedOrders);
            }

            //Return orderList with fetched attributes
            return View(confirmedOrder);
        }
```

I am using the passed id in a LINQ expression to tell the DBAccessor which order we are currently working with. Afterwards I am associating the view model attributes to the attributes found within the SQL database, by creating an object of the view model (ConfirmOrderLineViewModel).

Additionally, i am returning the list 'confirmedOrder' to the view - this list was created globally and can be seen below:

```
public static List<ConfirmOrderLineViewModel> confirmedOrder = new List<ConfirmOrderLineViewModel>();
```

Secondly, i am using an additional action result to assign the passed input values (from the begin form) to the database attributes, afterwhich i am redirecting to the view seen above:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SendOrderActionFinal(int id, int Product, int Quantity, int Supplier)
        {
            OrderLine newOrderLine = new OrderLine();
            newOrderLine.OrderID = id;
            newOrderLine.ProductID = Product;
            newOrderLine.Quantity = Quantity;
            newOrderLine.SupplierID = Supplier;
            DBAccessor.OrderLine.Add(newOrderLine);
            DBAccessor.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("ConfirmOrderPage");
        }
```

Finally, as can be seen on my view, I am using an HTML begin form as well as several HTML helpers in order to acquire user input, which can then be sent over to the action result once the form is submitted.

My begin form is as follows:

```
<div class="confirmOrderLineItem">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("SendOrderActionFinal", "Home", new { id = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"] }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
        var currentOrder = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Confirm Order</h1>
            <p class="lead">Viewing Order Number: @currentOrder</p> 
        </div>
        <label>Product</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("Product", ViewBag.ProductList as SelectList, "Select Product", new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
        <br />
        <label>Quantity</label>
        @Html.TextBox("Quantity", null, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", required = "required", min = 1 });
        <br />
        <label>Supplier</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("Supplier", ViewBag.SupplierList as SelectList, "Select Supplier", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Supplier" })
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="insertOrderBtn">Insert</button><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send Order</button>
    }
</div>
```

Towards the bottom of the begin form, you can see that there are two submit buttons, one named 'Insert' and the other 'Send Order' - when 'Insert' is clicked, the currently entered inputs (within the begin form) should be added to the table as seen below, WITHOUT making any COMMITS to the database itself (The user should be able to return to the main view and the table should be completely discarded). However, when 'Send Order' is clicked, the entire tables contents need to COMMIT to the database.

The table:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Product</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Price (R)</th>
            <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (U18043039_HW6.ViewModels.ConfirmOrderLineViewModel confirmedOrder in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@confirmedOrder.ProductName</th>
                <td>@confirmedOrder.Quantity</td>
                <td>@confirmedOrder.Price</td>
                <td>@confirmedOrder.SupplierName </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My issue is:

Whenever i click on either 'Insert' or 'Send Order', i am met with a 'Server Error in '/' Application' error - saying that "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ConfirmOrderPage(Int32)'" Indicating that the id value being sent to the ConfirmOrderPage ActionResult is becoming null once the form is submitted. Why could this be? The order does commit to the database, and the table is updated - however, only if i were to go back and refresh the page myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `return RedirectToAction("ConfirmOrderPage");` is missing the the object RouteValues
try `return RedirectToAction("ConfirmOrderPage", new { id = id });`
As your ActionResult ConfirmOrderPage expects an int parameter

Comment: You're a proper legend mate. This fixed my problem. I hadn't known you could do that. Appreciate it!